# Deploy Alexa-bridge on Azure

Tags: azure, botframework, alexa-skills-kit

i have developed a bot using microsoft bot framework nodejs sdk. i want to use alexa-bridge https://github.com/CatalystCode/alexa-bridge to give my bot the alexa voice interface. i am actually stuck at the initial steps of deploying the bridge on azure.

when i click on deploy to azure button available on the alexa-bridge github page

[image]

it takes me to my azure portal

[image]

i know bot id, direct line secret but have no idea about server farm id field. Create server farm field takes true/false. what do i need to do to deploy the bridge on azure portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Server Farm Id` actually is your Web App `App Service Plan` name. And bool of `Create Server Farm` determine to whteher create a new App Service Plan. You can set the value as you want, Here is my test deployment:

[image]